# ImageView setColorFilter alpha lost

Tags: android, colors, imageview, colorfilter

I'm having trouble with `imageView.setColorFilter()`. In my app, I have dark mode (black background, white text) and light mode (white background, black text).

Targeting API 21+, I am using vector asset icons generated by Android Studio which is white, where by default `android:tint="#FFFFFF"` and `android:fillColor="#FF000000"` in the xml files.

As per [material design](https://material.io/design/iconography/system-icons.html#color), the icons have certain alpha applied for different status. I am using status of `Active + Unfocused`, where for black icon =  `#8A000000` and white icon = `#B3FFFFFF`.

In dark mode, the icon will appear greyish over the black background, which is exactly how it should be with alpha applied. However, in light mode, the icon is 100% black regardless of the alpha above. I am applying the color using `imageView.setColorFilter()` with default `PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP`.

What is happening here and how can I solve it? Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While writing this question, I have experimented with a few things and came to solved the problem myself.

The issue is that the icon itself is BLACK (`#FF000000`) as per vector xml . Android Studio tinted it with white only.

Using `PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP`, the blending of source and destination pixels (which are both black) hence does not result in visible change. In order to fully replace the original icon color, I used `PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN` instead. In this case, I can use the same vector xml in both modes.

As per official docs

> PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP - Keeps the destination pixels that are not covered by source pixels. Discards destination pixels that are covered by source pixels. Discards all source pixels.
>
> PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN - Keeps the source pixels that cover the destination pixels, discards the remaining source and destination pixels.